# Is there a screensaver settings GUI for OpenBox/LXDE?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, openbox

I am using Lubuntu and I can't find any GUI for screensaver settings. 
I am missing something ?

Lubuntu 13.10 .

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu *is* it?

Comment: Are you looking for xscreensaver-demo ?

Answer (score 8):

What about this:

```
Menu>Preferences>Screensaver Preferences
```

Comment: It is indeed right. Since this is an answer, you should not post it as a comment. :)

Comment: There is no `Screensaver Preferences` under `Menu>Preferences` in my LUbuntu 18.04...

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you check in *~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh* with your favorite text editor to see if it is launching xscreensaver.

If you can't launch xscreensaver, perhaps it was not installed; run `apt-get install -y xscreensaver`

Comment: There is no such directory on Lubuntu.

Comment: Are you using Lubuntu 13.10 ? Also, please try the apt-get install -y xscreensaver to make sure it's installed.

Comment: Yes, I am using 13.10, anyway how dows installing xscreensaver address my question of having a GUI for the screensaver setup ?

Comment: `Openbox` should be lowercased.

Answer (score 0):

To check your current `xset` configuration, open the terminal and type this:
`xset q`

You'll then be shown what's set. You can see there these which are the ones you want to change:

```
$ xset q
...
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  600
...
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

After you fallowed the instructions above, if again you type xset -q in the terminal, you'll see that now it has changed to:

```
$ xset q
...
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  600
...
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Disabled
```

So now you can see that there's no blanking, no timeout and DPMS is disabled.

In the future if you want to turn them on again, just go to Menu/Control Menu/Settings/Default Applications for LXSession->Autostart and remove all the `xset` commands you entered.

If during a session you want to turn on some of the settings that you disabled, just enter in the terminal the proper commands following.

- enable blanking screensaver:
  `xset s blank`
- ten minute interval:
  `xset s 600 600`
- enable power management:
  `xset +dpms`

For more information you can type `xset` on the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>>, you'll be shown all the available options.

---

From here: http://lxle.net/forums/discussion/1463/disable-lockscreen